# Need XQuery syntax for 'if Exists()' behaviour in search api

Tags: marklogic

I have a requirement that we need to perform marklogic search only within the documents which have `<associated-bundles>` element in it's active version.

Below is our document structure

```
 <document document-status='active'>
 <file> 
     <version id=1 version-status='active'>
         <file-name/>
         <associated-bundles>
            <bundle doc-id="100082"></bundle>
            <bundle doc-id="100083"></bundle>
            <bundle doc-id="100000"></bundle>
         </associated-bundles>
         ...
         <file-level-visits>3</file-level-visits>
     </version>
     <version id=2 version-status='archived'>
         <file-name/>
         <uploaded-by>
         ...
         <file-level-visits>2</file-level-visits>
     </version>
     <version id=3 version-status='archived'>
         <file-name/>
         <uploaded-by>
         ...
         <file-level-visits>4</file-level-visits>
     </version>
 </file>
```

Considering above document structure, I need to perform search only on the documents which have `<associated-bundles>` element in their active version.

Note: There is only 1 active version in the document.

Below is the query to search only within active file "version-status". But in addition to this, I want to include 'ifExists' check of `<associated-bundles>` for the document.

```
cts:element-query (xs:QName ("version"),cts:and-query ((cts:element-attribute-value-query(fn:QName("","version"), fn:QName("","version-status"), "active", ("lang=en"), 1)
)));
```

Please let me know, how to achieve this.

Comment: did this work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the existence of an element using [cts:element-query()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-query) using the syntax below from the documentation:

```
cts:element-query(xs:QName("my-element"),cts:and-query( () ))
```

Comment: These days you can replace cts:and-query(()) with the simpler cts:true-query().

Comment: Thanks Jason. I had seen the true-query trick before and it never passed my mind. maybe a small update request for the docs is in order to freshen up the example.

Comment: I just sent a request to the docs team to make that update. `cts:true-query` is available in MarkLogic 8 and later.

Comment: Nice. Thanks Dave!