# In MarkLogic, how do I search in JSON documents using only the key?

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic

I have a bunch of JSON documents in my db. I need to perform delete operation on a few documents by searching the documents that have the particular field present in them {key only}. What query can I add to my code so that it finds all the documents with the field? I will be using them to get their values(integer), put them in an array and then use them one by one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263980/marklogic-query-for-documents-where-a-specific-json-property-is-not-defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding a bit on the link provided by George Bailey, you might want to use [`cts.uris()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uris) instead of `cts.search()` because `xdmp.documentDelete()` takes uri strings instead of documents:

```
const uris = cts.uris(
    null, 
    ['score-zero', 'unchecked'], 
    cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery('theKey', cts.trueQuery())
    );
xdmp.documentDelete(uris);
```

If it's a large number of documents, you might need to specify the start value and a limit on the call to `cts.uris()` to delete different slices of documents in multiple passes.

Hoping that helps,